# submit a value from span field

Tags: php, jquery, html, submit, form-submit

i have a from with a submit button

after using jquery the page will have :

```
for(var i=0 ; i <10 ; i++){
    '<span class="ioAddConcept">'+ currentConcept[i] +'</span>\n\
                  with\n\
                  <span class="ioAddRelation">'+ currentRelation[i] +'</span>\n\'
}
```

**(that piece of code is just an example)**

the variables currentConcept[] and currentRelation[] i got its values from database using Ajax

```
**i am using PHP**
```

and my question how to submit the page with these two variables ?

i mean in the server i hope something to be like this

```
 $concepts = $_POST['currentConcept[]']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get these values in jQuery like this:

```
var ioAddConcept = $(".ioAddConcept").html();
var ioAddRelation = $(".ioAddRelation").html();
```

Now you can set these values into form text boxes:

```
$('input.ioAddConcept').text( ioAddConcept );
$('input.ioAddRelation').text( ioAddRelation );
```

**OR** if you are submit form via AJAX request:

```
    $.ajax({
        url     : '/path/to/action.php',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : 'value1=' + ioAddConcept '&value2=' + ioAddRelation,
        success : function( data ) {
                    alert(data);
                  }
    });
```

Get these values on server side:

```
print_r( $_POST );
```

Comment: and in the server , how can i recieve them ?

Comment: i test your work and really it work and print this 
Array ( [0] => totti [1] => totti )

Comment: can i change [0] and [1] , check my results in my last comment

Comment: It should be like what you describe in `data` option of jQuery `ajax` function. In my example these should be `Array([value1]=>totti [value2]=>totti)`. Please show your `ajax` function code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/db64u/ 
this is the code of jquery , and in the css section i put my php code , and please see the code i have to send array , each value of that array have to be ([value1]=>totti , [value2]=>totti)

Comment: I did not find `ajax` function in jsfiddle ?

Comment: no it is in , search for the string `span class="ioAddConcept">` and u will find it

Comment: So you are sending your data like this: `$.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+currentConcept+"/TRUE", function....`

Comment: no no not like that , that is just the link for ajax call , dont worry about it, i am sending my data using a submit button in html

Comment: You need to call your script something like this if your want to get your data with specific keys in `$_POST`:

`"http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept?value1="+current‌​Concept+"&flag=TRUE"`

Comment: i hope i could but the all code , but it is very very large :)

Comment: i can't put any thing in the header because i am using .htaccess that alows just one variabls to be send , that is why i asked to send that values as it is a real input text field

Answer (score 2):

Add an ID to your span element

```
<span id="ElementID"> your variable text here</span>
```

Then use jquery to get the text out

```
var spanText = $('#ElementID').html();
```

Comment: i am not asking for using the value of those variables in my JS , i am asking how to send them to the server

Comment: You have to get the value out of the element before you can use it

Comment: What platform/technology are you using to submit the form? PHP, MVC3, etc?

Comment: @LinCR you should update the question with that info so we have all the info up front

Answer (score 2):

Something  like that

```
var currentConcept = $('currentConcept').html();
```

And then you can send this var as a param in you request to server

**Update**

```
$("form").submit(function() {
     var currentConcept = $('.currentConcept').html();   // it's an Array
     var currentRelation = $('.currentRelation').html(); // it's an Array

   $.ajax({
     url     : // your URL,
     data    : 'currentConcept=' + currentConcept '&currentRelation=' + currentRelation,
     success : function( html ) {
             // write your code here
              }
});
```

}

```
// server side (php)
$currentConcept  = $_GET('currentConcept');
$currentRelation = $_GET('currentRelation');
```

Comment: 1- would you give me an example , 2- those variables is in a loop , so would you tell me how to send it to the server

Comment: please just one thing , i don't want to ust $.ajax , check my code , http://jsfiddle.net/Wiliam_Kinaan/db64u/1/ , where and how can i used ur code in my jquery function , and thank you

Comment: which Jquery function you mean ?? And you can use another jqyery function like jquery --> $.get() OR $.post() .

Comment: i mean that one i am asking for , look at it , the currentconcept and currentRelation in the second AJAX call