# Cannot post span value by document.form.submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, http, submit

I'm writing a form and use `document.form.submit()` to post value, and I hope I can use `x = http.formvalue("")` to get the value well. But I found if I submit `<span>` value then I'll get `null`, if I replace `<span>` to `<input>` then I can get the value well, can anyone help me get the value only use `<span>`? thx!

HTML

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <ul class="formUl">
    <li>
      <span class="clm01">Phone:</span>
      <span class="clm02" id="phone" name="phone"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a class="submitBtn" href="#" onclick="apply()">Apply</a>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
function apply() {
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

Comment: Because only input, select, ... tags are posted back to the server. You could use a hidden field to store the same value as your span.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674277/submit-a-value-from-span-field

Comment: Thx for your answer, they all help me a lot. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`span` is not a form element. Form elements are `inputs`, `selects`, `radios`, `textareas`, etc. That is why it works when you change it to an `input`.

Comment: Thx! Are there any solution if I want use span?

Comment: Well... You could keep your span and then add a hidden text input like this:

`<input type="text"  name="phone" style="display:none;" value="add_some_phone_number"/>`

Comment: Thx a lot, I fixed :)